# Set a new environement variable: Requested registry access is not allowed

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I'am trying to write a code in C# that set an environment variable from two lists of variables name and their supposed content.
This how I am doing:

```
var VariableName = new[] {"ROOT"};
var VariableContent = new[] { "C:\\" };
var Variables = VariableName.Zip(VariableContent, (n, c) => new { Name = n, Content = c });
foreach (var Variable in Variables)
{
    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(Variable.Name) == null)
    {        
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(Variable.Name, Variable.Content, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);   

    }
```

the problem is that `SetEnvironmentVariable` method is rturning the following exception:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.

How can this be solved ?

Comment: If you don't have permission for `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine` try a lesser target.

Comment: Clearly the current user does not have access. Run the application in the context of a user whom does have access, or request elevation when needed.

Comment: is there any programmatic solution for this issue? I tried `new EnvironmentPermission(EnvironmentPermissionAccess.Write, Variable.Name).Demand();` but the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your application in administrator mode

Comment: is there any programmatic solution for this issue? I tried `new EnvironmentPermission(EnvironmentPermissionAccess.Write, Variable.Name).Demand();` but the same problem

Comment: That is the programmatic solution. If you want to set a machene level variable you need to make your program run as admin by adding a manifest with RequireAdministrator set.